# HttpWebRequest behaves differently from .NET 5.0 and .NET Framework

Tags: .net, .net-core, file-upload

Years ago I created a little program with .NET framework to upload a file in chunk.
Now I need to convert it in .NET Core (5.0) and I can't understand why it behaves so differently using the exact same code.

This is a **simplified** code that you can build as a console application in .NET Framework (version 4.7.2 in my test) and in .NET Core (5.0).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace TestUpload
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms);
                tw.Write(new string('0', 20000));
                tw.Flush();
                ms.Position = 0;
                byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
                PostForm("https://httpbin.org/post", bytes);
            }
        }

        static void PostForm(string postUrl, byte[] formData)
        {
            string boundary = String.Format("{0:N}", Guid.NewGuid());

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

            request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
            request.SendChunked = true;
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            request.Method = "POST";

            // This is for fiddler testing
            WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            request.Proxy = myproxy;

            // Start to send the form data to the endpoint.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int count = 0;
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (Stream inputStream = new MemoryStream(formData))
                {
                    while ((count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                }
            }

            request.GetResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

Now execute the two console apps and you'll find that the posted data are completely different (I used Fiddler as a traffic analyzer).

**.NET Framework**

```
[...]
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expect: 100-continue

1000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000[...]
1000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000[...]
1000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000[...]
[...]
```

**.NET Core**

```
[...]
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

4E20
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000[...]
```

In my application I need to track any chunk uploaded to feed a progress bar.
Since .NET Core seems to declare a chunked body but doesn't seem to separate the body in any way (the zeros string representing the file is in a single row) the notification I send to the progress bar for any chunk doesn't correspond to the real network traffic. So the upload seems to finish immediately when instead it is still uploading.

Can anybody help me to send a real chunked file in .NET Core please?

And please, please, please... don't explain me that usually a multipart form should have some metadata to describe the file, that if I define a boundary I would use it to enclose the binary data, that you should see my code to feed the progress bar, and so on... I perfectly know all these things.
The code and the resulting header have been simplified to focus the only problem I have: the .NET Core send the binary data as a whole, the .NET Framework instead separates the chunk in lines with a "1000" string separator allowing me to monitor the network traffic.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am desperately looking for another difference between .net framework and .net 5, seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913237/httpclient-same-code-gives-different-exceptions-in-net-framework-and-net-5-0
..just hoping you solved this and it is somehow related. :-)

Comment: I'm still in this mess...