# HttpClient - same code gives different exceptions in .NET Framework and .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-framework-version

I am trying to update a .net framework 4.5 project to .net 5.0, but ran into a problem. After some headache I found it to be HttpClient.GetAsync(). It gives me different exceptions depending on the target framework.

In .NET Framework 4.5 I get the following exception: (Correct behaviour)
"An error occurred while sending the request." with the inner exception "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

While in .NET 5.0 I get this:
"The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing." with the inner exception "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request."

The problem is that the application get no response at all in .NET 5.0, while in .NET Framework 4.5 it immediately throws the exception.

I have the following piece of code:

```
  string deviceAddress = "https://192.168.1.173:443";
  HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
  Uri uri = new Uri(deviceAddress);

  try
  {
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
```

Please advice, I am new to .NET 5.0.

I have tried the 'AcceptAllCertificates'. In .NET Framework 4.5 the exception disappears as expected, but in .NET 5.0 there are no difference, the function never gets called.

```
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = AcceptAllCertificates; 

protected bool AcceptAllCertificates(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
  return true;
}
```

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. HttpClient has change a **lot** in .NET Core and is actually far better. Meanwhile that `AcceptAllCertificates` is a security horror that makes HTTPS useless - HTTPS isn't used to encrypt communications, it's used to ensure nothing can get between the two, impersonate each other and thus intercept messages. That's done by *validating the certificates* before connecting

Comment: If you had to disable certificate validation in .NET Framework it means you were already using an invalid certificate. Perhaps a self-signed development certificate. The solution to this isn't disabling certificate validation, it's adding that certificate to the list of trusted certificates. In .NET Core the SDK itself generates and registers a self-signed certificate for development.

Comment: PS: the code you used is highly unusual. You should't need anything more than `HttpClient _client=new HttpClient(); ..... var response=await httpClient.GetAsync("https://192.168.1.173");` There's no reason to specify the port.

Comment: `The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.` what is the *actual, full exception text* and *actual code*? This could mean your application terminated while an async method was still executing. Or that the request timed out because the *service* didn't respond in time. If that service is written in .NET (Core) 5 it's using the trusted development certificate so there's no reason to throw an invalid certificate exception

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, thanks for your quick answers! I know I am using an invalid certificate. The difference here is that in .net framework I get an exception, while in .net (core) 5 I do not.

Comment: Perhaps because it's no longer invalid in .NET Core, if the SDK registered it. The certificate is provided by the service, not the client. What does the *service* do? We can't guess what you're doing from the snippet you posted, except to say it's suspicious and the error is *not* HTTP-related. If the *service* froze, you'd get such a timeout. If you google that error message you'll see it's caused because the service didn't respond in time.

Comment: To put it another way, I can create an example that shows there's no problem with HttpClient in less than 15t lines - that includes 2-3 lines for the client and the rest for the service and client using top-level statements and minimal APIs. Why do you assume it's not the service that froze?

Comment: I tried now. The timeout is set to 100 seconds, it gave me plenty of time to load the web page in a browser. The service responds as it should. (I have a certificate for the service installed in chrome for testing.)

Comment: I figured out the root cause: It's the company's vpn. The same code works fine on my private computer. Thank you Panagiotis for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question after some more hacking around, and hope it helps someone.

The problem in this case is most probably a VPN-issue. The 'fix' in this case was simply to set the Timeout to a low value:

```
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.0);
```

This way I get the timeout-exception instead, after an acceptable amount of time. This is of course not the solution but a workaround.